# Error preprocessor directives when building

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-2013

When building a VS2013 solution (migrated from VS8) I get the following error :

> Error 1   error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file
>   generated C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afx.h  38 Warning  2   warning C4996: 'MBCS_Support_Deprecated_In_MFC': MBCS support in MFC is deprecated
>   and may be removed in a future version of MFC.    C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afx.h    38

This is caused bij the following code :

```
    #ifdef _MBCS
// Warn about MBCS support being deprecated: see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=279048 for more information.
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(1 : 4996)
inline __declspec(deprecated("MBCS support in MFC is deprecated and may be removed in a future version of MFC.")) void MBCS_Support_Deprecated_In_MFC() { }

class MBCS_Deprecated_MFC
{
public:
    MBCS_Deprecated_MFC() { MBCS_Support_Deprecated_In_MFC(); }
};
#pragma warning(pop)
#endif
```

How can I find where _MBCS is defined in the solution. Find doesn't has any results.

Comment: Check the compilation command line arguments in the project properties.

Comment: These lines are empty.

Comment: Even if you find the `PreprocessorDefinitions` in your .vcproj files you cannot simply remove `_MBCS`. You will have to investigate, why it was set in the first place, and identify code that relies on it. This is non-trivial.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `_MBCS` symbol will be defined as a result of the settings in your project properties. Look at `General->Character Set` - this is what adds the required entries to the command line.

To continue using MBCS, you need to install the optional support from [Microsoft here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=40770)

As it notes in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z097dxa.aspx):

[image: msdn]

The code in your question actually gives a link to [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/07/08/mfc-support-for-mbcs-deprecated-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx), which discusses the changes and includes a link to the download:

```
// Warn about MBCS support being deprecated: see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=279048 for more information.
```

So, you can either download the patch from the link above or migrate your application to UNICODE.

Comment: I already installed the MFC libraries. This solved the original error I got. After installation I get the warning and error above.

Comment: @pistach ok then make sure you haven't set the `/WX` flag to treat warnings as errors. Try using `/W3` instead or add `#pragma warning(disable : 2220)` to your `stdafx.h`.

Comment: I changed the Character Set property in two files from "Use Multibyte Characterset" to "not set". Now my solution is build without error. Do you have any idea what the concequences of changing this can be? Or is it better to leave the characterset and change the Warning Level?

Comment: @pistach "Not set" means ANSI (rather than MBCS or UNICODE) - unless you need extended character sets for multi-language etc, there is little problem.

Comment: Anyone know how to suppress this warning? MBCS_Support_Deprecated_In_MFC

Comment: @devopsEMK Good spot, +1 for you :-)